# scala 2.10 callback at the end of a `Deadline`

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.10, along with the new `Future`/`Promise` API, they introduced a `Duration` and `Deadline` utilities ([as described here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html#utilities)). I looked around but couldn't find anything that comes with the scala standard library, to do something like:

```
val deadline = 5 seconds fromNow
After(deadline){
  //do stuff
}

//or

val deadlineFuture: Future[Nothing] = (5 seconds fromNow).asFuture
deadlineFuture onComplete {
  //do stuff
}
```

Is there anything like that available that I've missed, or will I have to implement this kind of behavior myself?

Comment: SIP-14 does not include a Scheduler service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite built in, but they provide just enough rope.

The gist is to wait on an empty promise that must disappoint (i.e., time out).

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test extends App {
  val v = new SyncVar[Boolean]()
  val deadline = 5 seconds fromNow
  future(Await.ready(Promise().future, deadline.timeLeft)) onComplete { _ =>
    println("Bye, now.")
    v.put(true)
  }
  v.take()
  // or
  val w = new SyncVar[Boolean]()
  val dropdeadline = 5 seconds fromNow
  val p = Promise[Boolean]()
  p.future onComplete {_ =>
    println("Bye, now.")
    w.put(true)
  }
  Try(Await.ready(Promise().future, dropdeadline.timeLeft))
  p trySuccess true
  w.take()
  // rolling it
  implicit class Expiry(val d: Deadline) extends AnyVal {
    def expiring(f: =>Unit) {
      future(Await.ready(Promise().future, d.timeLeft)) onComplete { _ =>
        f
      }
    }
  }
  val x = new SyncVar[Boolean]()
  5 seconds fromNow expiring {
    println("That's all, folks.")
    x.put(true)
  }
  x.take() // wait for it
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction, so I'm accepting. Now I'm wondering about the number of threads that will get created if I do something like `for(i<-0 to 1000) 2 seconds fromNow expiring { println(Thread.getCurrentThread.getName) }`... testing out on my own I'm seeing stuff like `ForkJoinPool-1-worker-800` which makes me a little uneasy.

Comment: Hmm.. disregard my concern in the previous comment. This seems to be no worse than the usual usage for Futures anyway.

Comment: Blocking is evil, but you didn't specify not-evil. I wouldn't try death by 0 to 1000 cuts.

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing it's a better idea to create a `ScheduledExecutorService` and scheduling runnables that just fulfil a promise.

Comment: Certainly, when I had to monitor timeouts on long-running jobs (tests in that case), I made a separate monitor to examine jobs in aggregate and complete their promises. But for a one-off, Awaiting a hopeless promise is ok; once again, SO spurs one to think outside the box, albeit briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a timestamp holder. For example you need to distribute execution of N sequential tasks, in T hours. When you have finished with the first one, you check a deadline and schedule next task depending on (time left)/(tasks left) interval. At some point of time `isOverdue()` occurs, and you just execute tasks left, in parallel.

Or you could check `isOverdue()`, and if still false, use `timeLeft()` for setting timeout on executing the next task, for example.

It's much better than manipulating with `Date` and `Calendar` to determine time left. Also Duration was used in Akka for timing.

Comment: I understand that the `Duration`/`Deadline` classes are just glorified timestamp holders - I was really just hoping for something built-in to the library so that I don't have to create a `ScheduledExecutorService` or a `Timer` thread and deal with low-level stuff. If there is no such thing already created, then I will accept "No" for an answer.

Comment: Timer is deprecated for ages. Scheduled message send can be configurated with actor system dispatcher: actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(deadline.timeLeft)(who ! ServerGatherStatisticsTick)        
Akka docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4

Comment: ... I would appreciate addition of implicit deadline to Futures library, that will check timeouts for us. It could be passed to executors same as transaction object in ScalaSTM